# CentOS Ioncube make_license is "Killed" each time I try to execute it

Tags: php, unix, licensing, centos, ioncube

I am trying to generate ioncube license using "make_license" generator provided by ioncube for Unix systems. It works on my desktop Ubuntu system, but does not work on my CentOS webserver.

Each time I try to run the file, I get message "Killed" in terminal, so it looks like this:

```
[root@myserver test]# ./make_license --passphrase 'secret' --expire-in 20d > 'license.txt'
Killed
[root@myserver test]#
```

Just a weird message "Killed" after I execute the file and nothing else. I also tried placing "sudo" in front of "./make_license --passphrase ....." and it worked, but license file was generated empty (0 bytes).

I have tried chmod 755 and 777 to "make_license", and it didnt help. Also I tried stopping "/etc/init.d/amavisd", just in case it's antivirus, but same thing.

My server configuration is: CentOS-6.2 64bit + Nginx, PHP-FPM, APC, php-ioncube-loader-4.2.2-2.el6.art.x86_64

I found the same question on Ioncube forum without answer: 
http://forum.ioncube.com/viewtopic.php?t=3909&sid=8d595f7005f5b851479a00d387635ad7

Please share any ideas you might have.

Answer (score 1):

So I contacted the ioncube support and this is what they replied:

> There are two things to check here:-
>
> 1. That you have uploaded the make_license program to your server in binary mode and not in ASCII mode.
> 2. You have the 32-bit compatibility libraries installed (as make_license, like the Encoder, is a 32-bit program).
>
> The loader does not matter in this case as it has nothing to do with
>   the problem with make_license.
>
> You *may* need to install the 32-bit compatibility libraries for
>   CentOS for make_license to work as that is a 32-bit program.
>
> The make_license file will be a binary in any case but if you uploaded
>   to your server via FTP in ASCII mode rather than binary then that
>   might corrupt the file and cause the "killed" message. So please
>   upload make_license again, making sure to choose binary mode in your
>   FTP client.

So I checked my make_license file:

```
[root@localhost test]# file make_license

make_license: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
```

It says that file is "executable", which I thought is = "binary".

But apparently it wasn't binary. Because after I uploaded it again, making sure that transfer mode was "binary" in my FTP client - everything worked. No more "Killed" message and licenses are generated.

Hope this helps someone.